# Accessing static files in SCD

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

In the `.NET CORE` application, I'm using static files in `wwwroot` folder.
 while running it as `dotnet run` the `index.html` file is displayed smoothly and normal at `localhost:port/` but after publishing the app as `SCD` self-contained development package, and run the `.exe` generated file, the `static files` are not displayed at the `localhost:port/`.

In the developer screen of the browser, I got `404 error` that is file not found.

Comment: Are you running the .exe file from the `publish` directory?

Comment: Yes @svick, actually I tried both, the one inside the 'publish' and the one outside it, none of them worked it.

Comment: What was the working directory when you ran it?

Comment: @svick not getting your point, kindly have  alook to my proposed answer, i tried o explain the issue in another way instead of updating the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40612533/accessing-static-files-in-scd/40625065#40625065

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the corresponding statement in your `project.json`:

```
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },
```

Comment: Thanks, it did the copy of the files into the `publish` folder, instead the manual copy/paste I did.

Comment: can you help with this pls: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40626872/attaching-a-file-from-zip-folder

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the files other than `.cs` as not packaged, and needed to be added manually to the `publish` folder.

I've the below example for sending html file as attached email:

[image]

and the files structures are:

`project.json`

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true
 },
"runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {},
    "win10-x86": {}
},
"dependencies": {
   "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
   "Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime.CoreCLR": "1.0.2",
   "Microsoft.NETCore.DotNetHostPolicy":  "1.0.1",
   "MailKit" : "1.10.0"
 },
"frameworks": {
   "netstandard1.6": { }
 }
}
```

`program.cs`

```
using System;
using System.IO;  // for File.ReadAllText
using MailKit.Net.Smtp;   // for SmtpClient
using MimeKit;  // for MimeMessage, MailboxAddress and MailboxAddress
using MailKit;  // for ProtocolLogger

namespace sendHTMLemail
 {
     public class newsLetter
     {
         public static void Main()
         {
             var message = new MimeMessage();
             message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("INFO", "info@xx.com.sa"));
             message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("MYSELF", "myself@xx.com.sa"));
             message.Subject = "Test Email";
             var bodyBuilder = new BodyBuilder();
             string htmlFilePath = "./html-files/msg.html";
             bodyBuilder.Attachments.Add("./html-files/msg.html");
             bodyBuilder.HtmlBody = File.ReadAllText(htmlFilePath);
             message.Body = bodyBuilder.ToMessageBody();

            using (var client = new SmtpClient (new ProtocolLogger ("smtp.log")))
            {
                   client.Connect("smtp.office365.com", 587);
                   try{
                       client.Authenticate("info@xxx.com.sa", "inof@PSWD");
                   }
                   catch{
                       Console.WriteLine("Authentication Faild");
                    }

                    try
                       {
                       client.Send(message);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                        {
                             Console.WriteLine("ERROR");
                    }
                    client.Disconnect(true);
            }
       }
   }
 }
```

The above worked very fine, and the `publish` had been prepared running the below commands:

```
dotnet restore

dotnet build -r win10-x64
dotnet build -r win10-x86

dotnet publish -c release -r win10-x64
dotnet publish -c release -r win10-x86
```

but while executing the `.exe` file in the `publish` folder, it gave an error that the file `pathTo/html-files/msg.html` is not found.

Once I copied the folder  required to the `publish` folder as below, everything worked fine:

[image]

**NOTE**
If you do not need the public/static file to be seen by the user, then you can compress them, then read them from memory stream, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40626872/attaching-a-file-from-zip-folder/40634704#40634704)