# Attaching a file from .Zip folder

Tags: c#, .net-core, mailkit

Using `MailKit` in `.NET CORE` an attachement can be loaded using:

```
bodyBuilder.Attachments.Add(FILE);
```

I'm trying to attach a file from inside a ZIP file using:

```
using System.IO.Compression;    

string zipPath = @"./html-files.ZIP";
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath))
{
     //   bodyBuilder.Attachments.Add("msg.html");
          bodyBuilder.Attachments.Add(archive.GetEntry("msg.html"));
}
```

But it did not work, and gave me `APP\"msg.html" not found`, which means it is trying to load a file with the same name from the `root` directory instead of the `zipped` one.

Comment: The only thing i may suggest now is just try to carefully debug through the statements of the program, look at the variables' values. For example, you should add `archive` variable to the watch window in VS and investigate it's properties - especially `Entries`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bodyBuilder.Attachments.Add()` doesn't have an overload that takes a ZipArchiveEntry, so using `archive.GetEntry("msg.html")` has no chance of working.

Most likely what is happening is that the compiler is casting the ZipArchiveEntry to a string which happens to be `APP\"msg.html"` which is why you get that error.

What you'll need to do is extract the content from the zip archive and then add *that* to the list of attachments.

```
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

string zipPath = @"./html-files.ZIP";
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead (zipPath)) {
    ZipArchiveEntry entry = archive.GetEntry ("msg.html");
    var stream = new MemoryStream ();

    // extract the content from the zip archive entry
    using (var content = entry.Open ())
        content.CopyTo (stream);

    // rewind the stream
    stream.Position = 0;

    bodyBuilder.Attachments.Add ("msg.html", stream);
}
```

Comment: looks nice will test it tomorrow and confirm you, considering I'm new to c# and just read little about 'memoryStream' like to ask you what if I've more than a file, shall I create different steam for each one, or add them together in single steam, if so, B how can I read the correct steam related to each file, and what about memory cleaning, when the stream is removed from the memory, shall I remove it manually, thanks

Comment: Your follow up questions answer your first question. It's impossible to use a single stream. You need 1 stream per file.